# Handlebars.js if...else not working

Tags: if-statement, handlebars.js, thorax.js

My array is:

```
[    {    status: failed    },    {    status: passed    }    ]
```

The if...else condition of my Handlebars.js template is:

```
<td><a class="{{#each status}} {{#if failed}} fail {{else}} pass {{/if}} {{/each}}"></a></td>
```

The above condition is not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on here. First off, `failed` and `passed` in your array are variables. Are they booleans, strings, or otherwise? Either way, the values of those variables are getting passed in to your template, not their name, so `{{#if failed}}` isn't going to work because it's looking for a variable with a name of 'failed' which doesn't exist. Also, each object in your array has a *key* of status, but `{{#each status}}` iterates over an array with a name of status, so there's a mismatch there as well.

Finally, I think your logic might be wrong- if this worked, it would have this output:

```
<td><a class="fail pass"></a></td>
```

because your loop is within a single `<a>` element. I'm guessing you want to have an individual table cell per status. If that's correct, you'd want something like this:

```
{{#each status}}<td><a class="{{#if failed}} fail {{else}} pass {{/if}}"></a></td>{{/each}}
```

with a data structure like:

```
{status: [{failed: true}, {failed: false}]}
```

like in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/carpeliam/5fgr10gf/.